# Matching rest of string in perl-style regex

Tags: regex, pcre

How do I match something thats "A known part (unknown word) (the rest of the string)" in a perl-style regex (PCRE)?

Comment: PCRE is not Perl Compatible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755168/perl-myths/933070#933070

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
/^KNOWN PART (\w+) (.*)$/
```